# Should access to properties of other classes through association be made explicit or are they implicit?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm working on a project where I'm using an SDK that provides things I need via some classes. I've named these `ProviderProvider` and `Provider`, that grant access to `OneThing` that is an `IThing`.
An example is shown here

[image: shown here].

My question is: What is the correct (or best) way to show that the `Model` provides the list of `OneThing`s to the `View` through those classes?

1. Do you show this explicitly as in my example, by drawing a dependency arrow from `Model` to `OneThing`? That doesn't seem right to me and quickly becomes visually cluttered.
2. Do you not explicitly define that relationship, but is it simply implicitly defined through the other relationships?
3. Do you define that relationship semi-explicitly through attributes, notes or some other way?

What relations and attributes should I add/remove specifically and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the implicit relationship since you use this class as a type of data returned by Model so you do not need to add that relationship explicitly.

It may be useful though, especially for classes that are core in the system, to add a diagram with dependencies only. Then you don't care about relationships between other classes, you only show on one diagram all classes that depend on the core one (it may be even more than one diagram).

One hint - in Case tool (like EA) even if you don't intend to show the relationship on the diagram since it is indicated implicitly it is still good to create the explicit dependency and just remove the arrow. This will support the traceability through tools like traceability matrix or dependency tree.